# Calculating a conditional expectation (probability theory)

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables with the joint probability density function $f_{xy}(x,y)=(15/4) x y^2$ for $0 < 2 y \leq x \leq 2$ and $0$ otherwise.

Calculate ${\cal E}[X^2+Y^2 \leq 1 | X \geq 0.5]$

Comment: But you must have tried something. Could you show your work first?

Comment: I am a beginner... but are you supposed to calculate $E[X^2+Y^2 \le 1 | X \geq 0.5]$ or $P[X^2+Y^2 \le 1 | X \ge 0.5]$ I've seen questions that ask to calculate $E[g(X,Y) \mid A]$ but not when $g(X,Y)$ is a statement like that. Again I'm a noob

Comment: Hi,thanks for your answer.Iam supposed to calculate expectation not probability and what you mentioned is exactly where i don't understand. I mean expectation of an event conditioned on another event that's the reason i cannot solve this